# Pyqt не вызывается finished у QNetworkReply

Tags: python, сеть, pyqt

```
def saveServer(self):
    name = 'tmp.png'
    url = 'http://localhost:5000/save'

    self.image.save(f"./{name}")

    with open(f"./{name}", 'rb') as img:
        files = {'image': (name, img, 'multipart/form-data', {'Expires': '0'})}

        with requests.Session() as s:
            r = s.post(url, files=files)
            request = r.request
            request.prepare(method="POST", url=url)

            request_qt = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url))

            for header, value in request.headers.items():
                request_qt.setRawHeader(bytes(header, encoding="utf-8"),
                                        bytes(value, encoding="utf-8"))

            manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
            manager.finished.connect(self.saveServerFinished)
            reply = manager.post(request_qt, request.body)
            reply.finished.connect(self.saveServerFinished)

def saveServerFinished(self, reply: QtNetwork.QNetworkReply):
    print('Saved')
```

Comment: reply выходит за пределы области видимости ( своей короткой жизни) и удаляется великим очистителем, поэтому никаких сигналов от него и не приходит. Чтобы сохранить ему жизнь, например добавьте его в self

Comment: Кст, а сигнал от `manager.finished` ведь срабатывает? Там `reply`, думаю, будет тот же, от которого вы сигнал ждали: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished

Comment: теперь я получаю ответ, но почему-то стало отсылаться два запроса, один с файлом, а второй без

Comment: Это так присылается EOF. пустой буфер это индикатор что файл прилетел

Comment: а как можно отследить, что это пришел EOF для файла, а не просто запрос, допустим, через curl с пустым телом?